How can i get the content(text) of a Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphItemBody in Powershell?
At the moment i get the email data as follows:
 $messages = Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -UserId $mailboxUserId -MailFolderId $folderName 
 $messages.Subject;
 $messages.Body 
 $messages.Content;

But the Body is of type Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphItemBody. How can i actually get what the body content is in text ?

According to this link you could do it like that ($messages.Body.Content -replace '</p>',"rn" -replace "<[^>]+>",'' -replace "&nbsp;",' ').trim()
